# Анимация поворота ячеек таблицы на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, анимация

Вот задание по JavaScript, которое я пытаюсь решить.

**Задача:**

1. Сделать сетку 4x4 из блоков.
2. Ниже расположить кнопку [start], при нажатии на которую текст в ней изменится на [in progress], а ячейки в сетке начнут переворачиваться на 180 градусов по очереди (важно заметить, что анимация следующей ячейки должна начинаться перед тем, как закончится анимация предыдущей).
3. После окончания эффектов вывести сообщение об успехе и кнопку снова изменить на [start].
4. Всю служебную информацию записывать в консоль (старт прогресса / старт анимации ячейки / окончание анимации ячейки / окончание прогресса).

   - P.S. эффект для ячеек сетки нужно реализовать на CSS.
   - P.S.S. если сделать сетку 4x5, ваш код должен работать.
   - P.S.S.S. кроссбраузерность будет плюсом.

Видео с примером реализации: [**смотреть**](https://youtu.be/MpsQXlyTyT0).

===

Мой старый код(можно не смотреть, тогда я еще почти не знал JavaScript):
*Ответ пользователя **wNow** шел для этого кода(точнее он все полностью за меня написал, за что ему благодарность).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button.action').click(function() {
    console.log('---PROGRESS START---');
    console.log('Cell 1 Animation START');
    $("tr.one td:nth-child(1)").addClass("takeover");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 1 Animation END');
    }, 1200);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 2 Animation START');
      $("tr.one td:nth-child(2)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 300);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 2 Animation END');
    }, 1500);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 3 Animation START');
      $("tr.one td:nth-child(3)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 600);;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 3 Animation END');
    }, 1800);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 4 Animation START');
      $("tr.one td:nth-child(4)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 900);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 4 Animation END');
    }, 2100);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 5 Animation START');
      $("tr.two td:nth-child(1)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 1200);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 5 Animation END');
    }, 2400);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 6 Animation START');
      $("tr.two td:nth-child(2)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 1500);;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 6 Animation END');
    }, 2700);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 7 Animation START');
      $("tr.two td:nth-child(3)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 1800);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 7 Animation END');
    }, 3000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 8 Animation START');
      $("tr.two td:nth-child(4)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 2100);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 8 Animation END');
    }, 3300);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 9 Animation START');
      $("tr.three td:nth-child(1)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 2400);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 9 Animation END');
    }, 3600);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 10 Animation START');
      $("tr.three td:nth-child(2)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 2700);;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 10 Animation END');
    }, 3900);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 11 Animation START');
      $("tr.three td:nth-child(3)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 3000);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 11 Animation END');
    }, 4200);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 12 Animation START');
      $("tr.three td:nth-child(4)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 3300);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 12 Animation END');
    }, 4500);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 13 Animation START');
      $("tr.four td:nth-child(1)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 3600);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 13 Animation END');
    }, 4800);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 14 Animation START');
      $("tr.four td:nth-child(2)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 3900);;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 14 Animation END');
    }, 5100);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 15 Animation START');
      $("tr.four td:nth-child(3)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 4200);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 15 Animation END');
    }, 5400);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 16 Animation START');
      $("tr.four td:nth-child(4)").addClass("takeover")
    }, 4500);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Cell 16 Animation END');
      console.log('---PROGRESS END---');
    }, 5700);
  });
  /*#############################################*/
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #212120;
}


/* begin Content */

.content {
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content table {
  margin: auto;
}

.content table tbody tr td {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  background-color: #4989C7;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #212120;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.content table tbody tr td.takeover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition: 1.2s;
}

.content button {
  background-color: #4989C7;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.content button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* end Content */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin Content -->
<div class="content">
  <!-- begin Table -->
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="one">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="two">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="three">
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="four">
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- end Table -->
  <button class="action" type="button"><span>start</span></button>
</div>
<!-- end Content -->
```

======= **Обновлено 30.03.17** =======

Получив знания по JavaScript, написал данный код(по нему и будет вопрос):

```js
'use strict';

function startFliping() {
  var score = 0;
  screen.innerHTML += '-- PROGRESS START -- <br>';
  button.innerHTML = 'in progress';

  (function flip() {
    var thisScore = score;
    var td = tdList[thisScore];

    if (thisScore != tdList.length) {
      screen.innerHTML += 'Cell ' + (thisScore + 1) + ' Animation START <br>';
      screen.scrollTop += screen.offsetHeight; // Добавил скролл, в задании нет, но на видео есть.
      td.style.transition = '1s';
      td.style.transform = 'rotateX(180deg)';

      td.addEventListener('transitionend', function() { // Отслеживаю окончание анимации.
        screen.innerHTML += 'Cell ' + (thisScore + 1) + 'Animation END <br>';
        screen.scrollTop += screen.offsetHeight;

        if (thisScore + 1 == tdList.length) { // Здесь проверка, если подходит, завершаем.
          screen.innerHTML += '-- PROGRESS END -- <br>';
          alert('sucess');
          button.innerHTML = 'start';
          screen.scrollTop += screen.offsetHeight;

          for (var i = 0, length1 = tdList.length; i < length1; i++) {
            tdList[i].style.transition = '0s';
            tdList[i].style.transform = 'rotateX(0)';
          }
        };

      });

      score++;
      setTimeout(flip, 200);
    };
    return;
  })();

};

var flipFlops = document.querySelector('.flipFlops');
var button = flipFlops.querySelector('.button');
var screen = flipFlops.querySelector('.screen');
var tdList = flipFlops.querySelectorAll('td');

button.addEventListener('click', startFliping);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

td {
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: #4289CE;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.flipFlops {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

.screen {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #4289CE;
  color: #fff;
  width: 380px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  background: #4289CE;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flipFlops">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="screen"></div>
  <a class="button">start</a>
</div>
```

- Использовал рекурсию.
- Добавил комментарии в код.
- Я новичок в js.

**Мой вопрос:** Первый раз запускаем, все как надо, но если еще запустить(без перезагрузки страницы), то появляется баг, а именно двойные надписи `Animation END` и двойной `alert`, третий раз запускаем уже три раза и т.д.(хочется чтобы было как при первом запуске). Я долго с этим возился, предполагаю, что проблема с `addEventListener('transitionend'` Как поправить не знаю, буду рад получить помощь(хочу узнать из-за чего ошибка и можно ли поправить не меняя сильно код).

Comment: в чём заключается проблема и ваши вопросы?

Comment: а вдруг будущий работодатель тоже читает "Stack Overflow"?)

Comment: Приложите к вопросу ваш код...... опишите в чем заключается ваша проблема, трудности, ибо непонятно к чему эта задача тут........и да, видео спокойно конвертируется в GIF,  который можно впихнуть в вопрос без всяких ссылок

Comment: Это тестовое задание от работодателя по JS. Сам корректно сделать не могу, прошу помощи. В чем вопрос? Удивительно, но вопрос в задаче указан и по пунктам разбит ! Если я могу это сделать сам, зачем мне здесь это писать и ставить такую задачу? или я написал здесь не "вопрос", а "ответ"? Все тоже самое я мог написать в другом виде и комментариев "о работодателе" не возникло бы, видимо кто-то не ценит прямоту и честность, нужно историю красивую придумать? Это мой первый вопрос здесь и я удивлен комментариям и минусам. Моя благодарность ответившему!

Comment: @alexandrkazakov, если вам нужно просто сделать за вас задание, то нужный вам ресурс это сайт фрилансеров.  А здесь людям помогают достичь того, чтобы они сами могли делать такие задания, вы же изначально просто скинули ТЗ без кода и вопросов. Поэтому такие комментарии и минуса.

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет ни одного знака вопроса. Зато присутствует слово **задача**. Не кажется вам логичным, что вас и спрашивают **в чем вопрос?** ? Ибо это походит на задание для фрилансеров..... Или вы считаете тут собрание экстрасенсов и должны угадать ваши мысли?

Comment: Удивительны ваши комментарии! Задача и вопрос! Задача в разделе "вопросов", возможно это не вопрос? Или чья это задача? возможно тоже нужно указать, что это моя задача? вопрос к кому адресован, также нужно указать? Здесь скорее вопрос о нашем понимании русского языка и отношения к нему, а также вопрос о том, что значит "придираться". Возможно, что я не совсем правильно оформил тему и зря сразу код свой не добавил, но и рейтинг мой здесь отображается и виден прекрасно, возможно стоит быть более снисходительным к человеку, оставившему свой первый вопрос на данном ресурсе?

Comment: Про то,что это задание от работодателя, я не скрываю, зачем придумывать сказки? Если у меня нет знакомых людей готовых мне помочь и у меня самого недостаточно опыта(т.к. я новичок), где же мне искать решение? Казалось бы на ресурсах подобных этому. Очевидно, что задача в разделе "вопросы" является вопросом и моей просьбой о помощи. Надеюсь мой комментарий будет кому-нибудь полезен, и мы, люди, будем более терпимы друг к  другу.

Comment: @alexandrkazakov дело в том, что много людей приходят и ставят именно задачи, чтобы за них сделали, при этом не приложив ни грамма усилий. Поэтому то, что в теле вопроса есть текст еще не значит, что это — вопрос. А раз вам наставили минусы, то наверное это не значит, что `Здесь скорее вопрос о нашем понимании русского языка `. Эт как раз вопрос к тому, как **вы** оформили вопрос. Вам стоит прочитать [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) как задавать вопросы. Как новичок, кстати, вас после регистрации должно было о данном разделе уведомить и вы бы после прочтения оформили лучше всё ;-)

Comment: Но так или иначе `самого корректно сделать не получается` - это слишком абстрактное высказывание. Можно описать, что именно не получается. В чем конкретно проблема? Проходить по пунктам и разбираться в вашем коде, чтоб выяснять что именно у вас не получается и что из пунктов вы сделали, а что нет — не ясно. В виду такой абстракции никому абсолютно не ясной опять же минусуют и закрывают вопрос

Comment: Ужас, единственному кто мне помог и ответил, за ответ минус влепили, что здесь происходит ... Спасибо тебе wNow !

Comment: Домашние задания не скидываються на стэк. Почитай правила составления вопросов. Ваш вопрос помимо вего нечитабелен и Вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @S.G. Здравствуйте!  Смотрите здесь на [SOru мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4995/234502) я создал тему по поводу этого вопроса. `Домашние задания не скидываються на стэк.` Что это значит? У меня нет возможности удалить вопрос, я его отредактировал/улучшил, теперь жду ответ. Пожалуйста напишите в той теме все свои замечания, я с радостью улучшу вопрос. Если не напишите, следовательно ваши претензии необоснованны.

Comment: Все кто минусуют, пожалуйста, посмотрите тему на [SOru мета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4995/234502) Если у вас есть претензии/пожелания по поводу данного вопроса, напишите там, и я постараюсь отредактировать/улучшить вопрос. Я написал код, поставил четко вопрос и прокомментировал его, вы ставите минусы без каких-либо комментариев, это лишает меня возможности понять, что именно вам не нравится. У меня нет возможности удалить данный вопрос.

Comment: Ответа на новый вопрос не дождался, решил сам задачу. Не стоило конечно `addEventListener('transitionend...` во внутрь той функции записывать ) Что интересно, после повторного открытия данного вопроса, из поставивших минус людей, только один написал небольшой комментарий здесь, и ни один не написал на мете. Хорошо, что есть и те, кто плюсы поставил. В таком случае награда  достается **wNow**, как единственному кто дал ответ. Получается, не так это и плохо, помочь новичку с одним единственным сообщением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function get(elem) {
  return document.getElementById(elem)
};
get('button').onclick = function() {
  get('console').innerHTML += '-- PROGRESS START --<br>';
  get('button').innerHTML = 'in progress';
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('success');
    get('console').innerHTML += '-- PROGRESS END --<br>';
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      get(i).style.transform = 'rotateX(0)';
      get(i).style.transition = '0s';
      get('button').innerHTML = 'start';
    }
  }, 2100);
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    get(i).style.transition = '0.5s';
    var t = i * 100;
    setTimeout(function(i) {
      get(i).style.transform = 'rotateX(180deg)';
      get('console').innerHTML += 'cell ' + (i + 1) + ' animation START<br>';
      setTimeout(function(i) {
        get('console').innerHTML += 'cell ' + (i + 1) + ' animation END<br>';
      }, 500, i)
    }, t, i);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  perspective: 400px;
}
td div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: #00accc;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#console {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
#button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #00accc;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id='0'>1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='1'>2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='2'>3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='3'>4</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id='4'>5</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='5'>6</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='6'>7</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='7'>8</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id='8'>9</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='9'>10</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='10'>11</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='11'>12</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id='12'>13</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='13'>14</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='14'>15</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id='15'>16</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id='console'>
  </div>
  <a id='button'>
start
</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, когда сниппет создаёте, нажимайте кнопку «привести в порядок». Форматирование кода очень помогает его читать.